# Bash Power/Exponent Raising ^0.16 and setting it a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to programming and Linux Bash I hope I'm explaining my problem properly.

So in my bash Linux script I'm taking in Airtemp and WindSpeed and I'm trying to raise Windspeed to ^0.16 to calculate Windchill Temp.

For Reference of what Windchill is.

```
#WindChill = (35.74 + (0.6215*AirTemp) - (35.75*(WindSpeed^0.16))+(0.4275*AirTemp*(WindSpeed^0.16))
```

After I Read Airtemp and Windspeed I do this `pow=$(echo "$WindSpeed^0.16" | bc)`. As I'm trying to raise it to 0.16 if I use ^ or ** I get the same result of
`Line 61: bc: command not found`

```
 # get operands and start computing based on the user's choice
        if [[ $choice -eq 1 ]] ; then
            echo Enter AirTemp value:
            read AirTemp
            echo Enter WindSpeed value:
            read WindSpeed
        pow=$(echo "$WindSpeed^0.16" | bc)
        WindChill=`echo "35.74 + (0.6215 * $AirTemp) - (35.75 * $pow) + (0.4275 * $AirTemp * $pow)"` 
        #WindChill = (35.74 + (0.6215*AirTemp) - (35.75*(WindSpeed^0.16))+(0.4275*AirTemp*(WindSpeed^0.16)) =77.95  EX: Airtemp 75F, Windspeed 3mph
            echo ----------------------------------------
            echo Windchill Temp of $AirTemp and $WindSpeed in F is $WindChill
            echo ----------------------------------------
            echo
```

Comment: `bc` is not a built-in function but external [program](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc). Install corresponding package in your distro.

Comment: When I do that and change it to "pow=$(($WindSpeed**0.16))" I get the error "3**0.16: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".16" " any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, floating point math is not supported by bash. You can use `bc`, just install package containing it.

Comment: Instead of mucking with bc, I'd switch to zsh or another shell that has native support for floating point. Or a completely different language.

Comment: `*` is a special symbol for bash, which expands to all files in the current directory (this process is called globbing). If you want to avoid this, you have to quote it, i.e. `\*` or `'*'`, depending on your taste.

Comment: As a side note: Since you decided to use `bc` anyway, you can write the whole calculation inside `bc`, instead of passing some formulas to it via `echo`. After all, `bc` is its own programming language. I would split the problem into two scripts: One in `bc`, which gets the operands from the command line, and one in `bash`, which prompts the user for the variables and invokes the bc-script. This also will make debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

On you line starting "Windchill=", you need to add "| bc" before the end-of-line backquote.

My own session logs,

```
Enter AirTemp value:
25
Enter WindSpeed value:
15
Runtime warning (func=(main), adr=10): non-zero scale in exponent
----------------------------------------
Windchill Temp of 25 and 15 in F is 26.2150
----------------------------------------
```

and

```
Enter AirTemp value:
10
Enter WindSpeed value:
25
Runtime warning (func=(main), adr=10): non-zero scale in exponent
----------------------------------------
Windchill Temp of 10 and 25 in F is 10.4800
----------------------------------------
```

don't seem to make sense.  Anything missing in that formula?